# How to add text under menu items

Tags: 7, theming

In my menu, I want to add some text under the menu item.  For example, I have 'About Us', and right under that, I want some subtext 'About our company'.

Do I add this in region.tpl.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) module for building your menu, and then whatever you type in your description depend on configuration will be print out too.

Under Advanced HTML `Settings > Hyperlinks` enable the "Include hyperlinks description (title) in hyperlinks text."

then simply add a `display: block;` style to the `ul li a span` to make it look the way you want.

you can see a demo [HERE](http://mehrpadin.net/demo/superfish/#block-superfish-2)

Comment: I'm using Superfish, but I don't see that option.

Comment: I updated the answer so you can get a clearer shot at this.

Comment: It keeps putting it on the same line as the item.  I want it below.  I tried to add a line break, but no avail.

Comment: Dude.. it's quite obvious that it will put it right next to the title, you need to do a little bit of css, right now I'm at work and busy, I'll give you the exact  instruction on how you do it when I get back home, and please consider choosing the answer as the right answer if it works! that's how we do it here

Comment: Updated the answer regarding your comment but I assume you might already figured that out

Comment: i am unable to see that option i have install module superfish. Can you please show me where i can found that option. I need to show text below the menu name like that. https://prnt.sc/k1wv81